# Crystal Report Merging SubReport issue

Tags: crystal-reports, report

i have a crystal report for VS2008 which contains 2 subreports, here's the details of main report.

```
Details a
Details b
Details c 
  Sub report 1
Details d  
  Sub report 2
```

I want the content to fill the remainder of page 1 and continue to page two etc. I tried to place the subreport 2 in details c but it overlapped the subreport 1..I have the Keep Together unticked but still 2nd subreports starts on a new page.

Any help please,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to uncheck the subreport's `Keep Object Together` setting.

Answer (score -1):

It is the functionality of the crystal reports where if the subreport doesn't find enough page then it will start in page 2, To the extent I know nothing much can be done.